# Two identical metadata requests, first one returns status 200, the 2nd one 404

Tags: odata, sapui5

Below you will find 2 metadata requests to the same OData Service. Except the cookie digit stream, they look like 2 drops of water, completely identical.

First one is triggered via the manifest.json file and its result is successful. Copied the data source definition to the manifest.json file of a second different application and put at work the debugger, expecting the same successful result.

**"dataSources": { "mainService": { "uri": "/Uni_Sandpit_Virtual/sap/opu/odata/SAP/ZCONTRACTS_SRV/", "type": "OData", "settings": { "odataVersion": "2.0" } } },**

To my absolute surprise the second metadata call returns 404 (not found). What do I miss here?

Best regards,

Greg

[Request returning status 200](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hWSG.jpg)
[Request returning status 404](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgjKz.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

​Found the issue, posting it in case some other runs on the same problem.

Missing "path" block inside the neo-app.json file:

**{ "path": "/Uni_Sandpit_Virtual", "target": { "type": "destination", "name": "Uni_Sandpit_Virtual" },**